# JBoss EAP 7.1.5 Why is server attempting authentication despite auth being turned off?

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, web.xml, java-security

I'm having a configuration issue with `<security-constraint>` / `<auth-constraint>` in JBoss EAP 7.1.5. Basically the server makes an attempt to authenticate a user whereas the user should be allowed to access the given path without being authenticated (by jboss-security).

**A bit more context**

Our old Javaee-8 application which runs on JBoss EAP 7.1.5 did receive an upgrade of its login-mechanism and we want to assure parallel operation (with the old and new login mechanism) for a certain time. We have therefore created two seperate paths on which the (same) application can be accessed:

- New login-mechanism on path `/baug1` e.g.: https://www.ourcompany.com/baug1
- Old login-mechanism on path `/baug` e.g.: https://www.ourcompany.com/baug

The old login-method is based on a custom jaas `<login-module>` while the new one is based on a REST API. In my understanding we therefore don't need a `<security-constraint>` with an `<auth-constraint>` for anything that runs under the `/baug1`-path. If I'm not mistaken, this should be the case with the following **web.xml** configuration:

```xml
<security-constraint>
   <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Baug1</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/baug1/*</url-pattern>
   </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
   <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resouce-name>BaugMainForward</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/baug/servlet/*</url-pattern>
   </web-resource-collection>
   <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>BaugMain</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/baug/secure/*</url-pattern>
   </web-resource-collection>
   <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>Customer</role-name>
      <role-name>Clerk</role-name>
   </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
   <auth-method>${jboss.web.default.authentication:HEADER}
   </auth-method>
   <realm-name>alcatraz-combined-user-role-property</realm-name>
</login-config>
<security-role>
   <role-name>Customer</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
   <role-name>Clerk</role-name>
</security-role>
```

I have tried different variations like for example removing the first `<security-constraint>` or setting the url-pattern for `Baug1` to `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` but to no avail. Meanwhile  our **jboss-web.xml** looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<jboss-web xmlns:jboss=http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee xmlns:javaee=http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee>
   <security-domain>alcatraz-combined-user-role-property</security-domain>
   <context-root>/</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

Finally the following security-domains have been defined in JBoss's **standalone.xml**:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:2.0">
    <security-domains>
        <security-domain name="alcatraz-combined-user-role-property" cache-type="default">
            <authentication>
                <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
                    <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                </login-module>
                <login-module code="RealmDirect" flag="optional">
                    <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                </login-module>
                <login-module code="com.ourourcompany.loginmodule.AlcatrazAssertedIdentityLoginModule" flag="optional" module="com.ourourcompany.loginmodule">
                    <module-option name="alcatraz.adapter.jndi.name" value="${alcatraz.adapter.jndi.name}"/>
                </login-module>
            </authentication>
            <mapping>
                <mapping-module code="com.ourourcompany.jboss.security.mappingmodule.AlcatrazRolesMappingProvider" type="role" module="com.ourourcompany.jboss.mappingmodule">
                    <module-option name="application" value="${alcatraz.application.name}"/>
                    <module-option name="alcatraz.adapter.jndi.name" value="${alcatraz.adapter.jndi.name}"/>
                </mapping-module>
                <mapping-module code="com.ourourcompany.jboss.security.mappingmodule.SimpleConfiguredRolesMappingProvider" type="role" module="com.ourourcompany.jboss.mappingmodule">
                    <module-option name="roles" value="ALLOW-ALL"/>
                </mapping-module>
            </mapping>
        </security-domain>
        <security-domain name="accept-all" cache-type="default">
            <authentication>
                <login-module code="com.ourourcompany.loginmodule.SimplePrincipalAcceptingLoginModule" flag="required" module="com.ourourcompany.loginmodule"/>
            </authentication>
            <mapping>
                <mapping-module code="com.ourourcompany.jboss.security.mappingmodule.SimpleConfiguredRolesMappingProvider" type="role" module="com.ourourcompany.jboss.mappingmodule">
                    <module-option name="roles" value="ALLOW-ALL"/>
                </mapping-module>
            </mapping>
        </security-domain>
        <security-domain name="alcatraz" cache-type="default">
            <authentication>
                <login-module code="com.ourourcompany.loginmodule.AlcatrazAssertedIdentityLoginModule" flag="required" module="com.ourourcompany.loginmodule">
                    <module-option name="alcatraz.adapter.jndi.name" value="${alcatraz.adapter.jndi.name}"/>
                </login-module>
            </authentication>
            <mapping>
                <mapping-module code="com.ourourcompany.jboss.security.mappingmodule.SimpleConfiguredRolesMappingProvider" type="role" module="com.ourourcompany.jboss.mappingmodule">
                    <module-option name="roles" value="ALLOW-ALL"/>
                </mapping-module>
                <mapping-module code="com.ourourcompany.jboss.security.mappingmodule.AlcatrazRolesMappingProvider" type="role" module="com.ourourcompany.jboss.mappingmodule">
                    <module-option name="application" value="${alcatraz.application.name}"/>
                    <module-option name="alcatraz.adapter.jndi.name" value="${alcatraz.adapter.jndi.name}"/>
                </mapping-module>
            </mapping>
        </security-domain>
        <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
            <authentication>
                <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
                    <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                </login-module>
                <login-module code="RealmDirect" flag="required">
                    <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                </login-module>
            </authentication>
        </security-domain>
        <security-domain name="jboss-web-policy" cache-type="default">
            <authorization>
                <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
            </authorization>
        </security-domain>
        <security-domain name="jboss-ejb-policy" cache-type="default">
            <authorization>
                <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
            </authorization>
        </security-domain>
        <security-domain name="jaspitest" cache-type="default">
            <authentication-jaspi>
                <login-module-stack name="dummy">
                    <login-module code="Dummy" flag="optional"/>
                </login-module-stack>
                <auth-module code="Dummy"/>
            </authentication-jaspi>
        </security-domain>
    </security-domains>
</subsystem>
```

Now despite this configuration the server would attempt to authenticate a user each time I call `/baug1` :

```sh
DEBUG [io.undertow.request] Matched default handler path /baug1/

DEBUG [io.undertow.request.security] Security constraints for request /baug1/ are [SingleConstraintMatch{emptyRoleSemantic=PERMIT, requiredRoles=[]}]

DEBUG [io.undertow.request.security] Attempting to authenticate HttpServerExchange{ GET /baug1/ request {Accept=[text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9], Accept-Language=[de-CH,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,fr-CH;q=0.6,fr;q=0.5,it-CH;q=0.4,it;q=0.3], X-Host=[app.dev.ourourcompany.ch], DNT=[1], User-Agent=[Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36 Edg/101.0.1210.39], ClientCorrelator=[92120c4b5b530fe26e05232c0cc23138], LoginUserDataHeaderName=[UserDataJSF], Front-End-Https=[On], Connection=[close], X-Forwarded-Proto=[https], RequestCorrelator=[YoeuM8QyMlGDv-W-X-4YZgAAAFg], X-Forwarded-For=[xx.xx.xx.12], Cookie=[JSESSIONID=xU4I5PXjcJz7LM_Cm7ZKAttYJLa_5flcAOGh7_7j.baug-84-4hw5t; SAT_CH_BAUG=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IkFUMjAxODA0MjMi...

DEBUG [io.undertow.request.security] Authentication outcome was NOT_ATTEMPTED with method io.undertow.security.impl.CachedAuthenticatedSessionMechanism@73c27b72 for HttpServerExchange{ GET /baug1/ request {Accept=[text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9], Accept-Language=[de-CH,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,fr-CH;q=0.6,fr;q=0.5,it-CH;q=0.4,it;q=0.3], X-Host=[app.dev.ourourcompany.ch], DNT=[1], User-Agent=[Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36 Edg/101.0.1210.39], ClientCorrelator=[92120c4b5b530fe26e05232c0cc23138], LoginUserDataHeaderName=[UserDataJSF], Front-End-Https=[On], Connection=[close], X-Forwarded-Proto=[https], RequestCorrelator=[YoeuM8QyMlGDv-W-X-4YZgAAAFg], X-Forwarded-For=[xx.xx.xx.12], Cookie=[JSESSIONID=xU4I5PXjcJz7LM_Cm7ZKAttYJLa_5flcAOGh7_7j.baug-84-4hw5t; dtCookie=v_4_srv_4_sn_D4077DA36E05A5EE30FD7B942BC956B3_perc...

DEBUG [com.xxx.jboss.security.web.authenticator.AbstractIdentityExtractor] Header 'UserDataJSF' is 'null'.

ERROR [com.xxx.jboss.security.web.authenticator.HeaderAuthenticatorHelper] Identity is 'null'!

DEBUG [io.undertow.request.security] Authentication failed with message UT000038: Authentication failed, requested user name 'null' and mechanism HEADER for HttpServerExchange{ GET /baug1/ request {Accept=[text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9], Accept-Language=[de-CH,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,fr-CH;q=0.6,fr;q=0.5,it-CH;q=0.4,it;q=0.3], X-Host=[app.dev.xxx.com], DNT=[1], User-Agent=[Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36 Edg/101.0.1210.39], ClientCorrelator=[92120c4b5b530fe26e05232c0cc23138], LoginUserDataHeaderName=[UserDataJSF], Front-End-Https=[On], Connection=[close], X-Forwarded-Proto=[https], RequestCorrelator=[YoeuM8QyMlGDv-W-X-4YZgAAAFg], X-Forwarded-For=[xx.xx.xx.12], Cookie=[JSESSIONID=xU4I5PXjcJz7LM_Cm7ZKAttYJLa_5flcAOGh7_7j.baug-84-4hw5t;

DEBUG [io.undertow.request.security] Authentication outcome was NOT_AUTHENTICATED with method com.xxx.jboss.security.web.authenticator.undertow.HeaderAuthenticationMechanism@3b28aa40 for HttpServerExchange{ GET /baug1/ request {Accept=[text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9], Accept-Language=[de-CH,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,fr-CH;q=0.6,fr;q=0.5,it-CH;q=0.4,it;q=0.3], X-Host=[app.dev.ourourcompany.ch], DNT=[1], User-Agent=[Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36 Edg/101.0.1210.39], ClientCorrelator=[92120c4b5b530fe26e05232c0cc23138], LoginUserDataHeaderName=[UserDataJSF], Front-End-Https=[On], Connection=[close], X-Forwarded-Proto=[https], RequestCorrelator=[YoeuM8QyMlGDv-W-X-4YZgAAAFg], X-Forwarded-For=[xx.xx.xx.12], Cookie=[JSESSIONID=xU4I5PXjcJz7LM_Cm7ZKAttYJLa_5flcAOGh7_7j.baug-84-4hw5t;

DEBUG [io.undertow.request.security] Sending authentication challenge for HttpServerExchange{ GET /baug1/ request {Accept=[text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9], Accept-Language=[de-CH,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,fr-CH;q=0.6,fr;q=0.5,it-CH;q=0.4,it;q=0.3], X-Host=[app.dev.ourourcompany.ch], DNT=[1], User-Agent=[Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36 Edg/101.0.1210.39], ClientCorrelator=[92120c4b5b530fe26e05232c0cc23138], LoginUserDataHeaderName=[UserDataJSF], Front-End-Https=[On], Connection=[close], X-Forwarded-Proto=[https], RequestCorrelator=[YoeuM8QyMlGDv-W-X-4YZgAAAFg], X-Forwarded-For=[xx.xx.xx.12], Cookie=[JSESSIONID=xU4I5PXjcJz7LM_Cm7ZKAttYJLa_5flcAOGh7_7j.baug-84-4hw5t; SAT_CH_BAUG=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IkFUMj...

DEBUG [io.undertow.request.security] Authentication result was CHALLENGE_SENT for HttpServerExchange{ GET /baug1/ request {Accept=[text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9], Accept-Language=[de-CH,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,fr-CH;q=0.6,fr;q=0.5,it-CH;q=0.4,it;q=0.3], X-Host=[app.dev.ourourcompany.ch], DNT=[1], User-Agent=[Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36 Edg/101.0.1210.39], ClientCorrelator=[92120c4b5b530fe26e05232c0cc23138], LoginUserDataHeaderName=[UserDataJSF], Front-End-Https=[On], Connection=[close], X-Forwarded-Proto=[https], RequestCorrelator=[YoeuM8QyMlGDv-W-X-4YZgAAAFg], X-Forwarded-For=[xx.xx.xx.12], Cookie=[JSESSIONID=xU4I5PXjcJz7LM_Cm7ZKAttYJLa_5flcAOGh7_7j.baug-84-4hw5t; SAT_CH_BAUG=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZC...

INFO  [io.undertow.accesslog] 10.94.12.14 - - [20/May/2022:17:05:23 +0200] GET /baug1/?pol_nr=xxxx HTTP/1.1 403 68 https://xxx.sharepoint.com/ Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36 Edg/101.0.1210.39 - -

DEBUG [io.undertow.request] UT005013: An IOException occurred: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at io.undertow.protocols.ssl.SslConduit.doWrap(SslConduit.java:846)
        at io.undertow.protocols.ssl.SslConduit.doHandshake(SslConduit.java:649)
        at io.undertow.protocols.ssl.SslConduit.access$900(SslConduit.java:63)
        at io.undertow.protocols.ssl.SslConduit$SslReadReadyHandler.readReady(SslConduit.java:1100)
        at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.handleReady(NioSocketConduit.java:89)
        at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:591)
```

So, to recap, my question is why the server makes an authentication-attempt when calling `/baug1` despite the fact that no `<auth-constraint>` is set for this path?

Any ideas are welcome! :)